# Log linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data set and I'm trying to do a log transformation on the data set, but I keep getting an error that says that Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

```
dataset3 = df_sheet_map['Set 3']
dataset3

X2 = dataset3.x
Y2 = dataset3.Y
plt.plot(X2, Y2, 'o')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
print('A logarthimic regression model will be used for this data set')

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
ln_Y2 = np.log(Y2)
plt.plot(X2, ln_Y2, 'o')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X2_train, X2_test, Y2_train, Y2_test = train_test_split(X2, Y2, test_size= 0.2, random_state=0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X2_test = X2_test.reshape(1, -1)

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X2_train,Y2_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict([[X2_test]])
```

but I am showing the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f9248c950ce4> in <module>()
      2 X2_train, X2_test, Y2_train, Y2_test = train_test_split(X2, Y2, test_size= 0.2, random_state=0)
      3 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
----> 4 X2_test = X2_test.reshape(1, -1)
      5 
      6 regressor = LinearRegression()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Can someone please help? I'm unsure how to reshape this code as before I did use `X2_test = X2_test.reshape(1, -1)` I got the error expected 2d array but got 1d.

Comment: try X2_test.values.reshape(1, -1)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993977/reshape-a-data-for-sklear ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
X = df['cases_log']
```

gave

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

but when I used

`X = df[['cases_log']]`

it worked.

Its problem is the one with single brackets returns a pandas Series obj and the other returns pandas data frame.