# Getting found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 4] error for RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm referring to [this Random Forrest Algorithm example](https://stackabuse.com/random-forest-algorithm-with-python-and-scikit-learn/) to predict rejection in different stages.

I'm fetching values from the database for `stages` and `reject_count`. And using `stages` values for `x` and `reject_count` values for `y`.
My code is:

```
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

    stages = [102, 103, 104, 106]
    reject_count = [1, 3, 1, 2]
    li = []
    li.append(stages)
    l2 = []
    l2.append(reject_count)
    x = np.array(li)
    y = np.array(reject_count)
    x.shape
    y.shape

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    print("===============")

    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

    regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
    print("x train", X_train)
    print("y train", y_train)
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
    print(y_pred)
```

Please guide me where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: Please post the full error trace

Comment: @desertnaut. there is no full error trace. getting only **Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 4]**

Comment: Where exactly? There is always a trace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thing going on here

First your x and y does not have the same dimension one is a list of list the other a list.
Secondly assuming that you want your data as an array of one observation per sample you should reshape your x value. more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993977/reshape-a-data-for-sklearn)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

stages = [102, 103, 104, 106]
reject_count = [1, 3, 1, 2]
#li = []
#li.append(stages)
#l2 = []
#l2.append(reject_count)
x = np.array(stages).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(reject_count)

print(x, y)
x.shape
y.shape

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
print("===============")

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
print("x train", X_train)
print("y train", y_train)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```